# Facebook iOS SDK 3.5 crashes on log in. -If facebook app is installed-

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, parse-platform

I don't know what has changed but it is really strange. I experience this crash on my apps as well as on other apps i download from app store.

Login button on my app behaves as expected but facebook app crashes. The only way through is to kill the facebook app and try again. If the facebook app is already running it always crashes.

I am using Parse's facebook utilities.

Anybody know why?

My code to trigger the login:

```
NSArray *permissionsArray = @[ @"email", @"user_relationships", @"user_birthday", @"user_location", @"user_likes", @"publish_actions"];
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    //blah blah
}];
```

Comment: are you getting any message on console ?

Comment: no, because the crash does not occur in my app. facebook app crashes. i suppose there is a bug in FB SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a hunch, try it without the publish_actions. If that works, look at splitting the permissions, or rather requesting publish permissions separately. Not totally sure what Parse are doing, but the 3.5 FB sdk requires, publish vs read permissions be requested separately